# SwiftData crash "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship"

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift-data

I am using SwiftData and SwiftUI, xcode 15 beta 5. I am trying to establish relationships between entities in DB. The is a User, a Book, and an Ownership between them.

```
struct asdApp: App {

    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: [Ownership.self, User.self, Book.self])

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .task {
                    let jon = User()
                    container.mainContext.insert(jon)
                    let book = Book()
                    container.mainContext.insert(book)
                    let o = Ownership(keeper: jon, book: book) // <-- crash here!!
                    container.mainContext.insert(o)
                }
        }
        .modelContext(container.mainContext)
    }
}
```

Here are the models, so that you have the full code:

```
@Model
final class User {
    @Attribute(.unique) let id: UUID

    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

@Model
final class Book {
    @Attribute(.unique) let id: UUID

    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

@Model
final class Ownership {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var keeper: User
    var book: Book

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), keeper: User, book: Book) {
        self.id = id
        self.keeper = keeper
        self.book = book
    }
}
```

Here is the full error:

```
Thread 1: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'keeper' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x60000212e5d0> (entity: Ownership; id: 0x600000243560 <x-coredata:///Ownership/tFADECEE1-82F7-4071-93B1-259354AE2E2A4>; data: {\n    book = nil;\n    id = \"6A63596F-66C2-45B3-91C0-FF24FF88B1B5\";\n    keeper = nil;\n}) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x60000214fed0> (entity: User; id: 0x600000299180 <x-coredata:///User/tFADECEE1-82F7-4071-93B1-259354AE2E2A2>; data: {\n    id = \"59B5122C-5CC6-4105-8F11-D48B6D46E63D\";\n}))"
```

**First question**: There is only one context, so why the crash?

There is no error if I change the order like this:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .task {
                let jon = User()
                let book = Book()
                let o = Ownership(keeper: jon, book: book)
                container.mainContext.insert(jon)
                container.mainContext.insert(book)
                container.mainContext.insert(o)
            }
    }
    .modelContext(container.mainContext)
}
```

But it doesn't work right, since it creates an extra book. Here is how I found out:

```
@main
struct asdApp: App {

    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: [Ownership.self, User.self, Book.self])

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .task {
                    clearAll(modelContainer: container)
                    let context = container.mainContext

                    let jon = User()
                    let book = Book()
                    let o = Ownership(keeper: jon, book: book)
                    context.insert(jon)
                    context.insert(book)
                    context.insert(o)

                    do {
                        for (index, user) in try  context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<User>()).enumerated() {
                            print("\(index) [USER]: id: \(user.id)")
                        }
                        
                        for (index, user) in try  context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Book>()).enumerated() {
                            print("\(index) [BOOK]: id: \(user.id)")
                        }

                        for (index, user) in try  context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Ownership>()).enumerated() {
                            print("\(index) [OWN]: id: \(user.id)")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Error while fetching all entities: \(error)")
                    }
                }
        }
        .modelContext(container.mainContext)
    }

    @MainActor
    func clearAll(modelContainer: ModelContainer) {
        do {
            (try modelContainer.mainContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<User>()))
                .forEach {
                    modelContainer.mainContext.delete($0)
                }

            (try modelContainer.mainContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Book>()))
                .forEach {
                    modelContainer.mainContext.delete($0)
                }

            (try modelContainer.mainContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Ownership>()))
                .forEach {
                    modelContainer.mainContext.delete($0)
                }

            try modelContainer.mainContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error while fetching all entities: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
0 [USER]: id: 14B69B68-1123-4658-9399-7E60E1051A2D
0 [BOOK]: id: 3A52F512-E82F-4574-B2EF-A0B9258EA094
1 [BOOK]: id: 99FC93F5-B81F-4060-A549-869472E53D1D
0 [OWN]: id: 7F1D089A-AF00-4AB0-A17A-275E8448FC20
```

**Second question**: Why 2 books, and how did they get different ids, if I only call init once (during debug it only comes there once)? I want 1 book, 1 user and 1 relationship.

Actual example is more complicated, this is the bare minimum I could achieve.

Comment: Properties in your model that are a relationship to another entity need the `@Relationship` decorator.  You don't really need the `Ownership` class. A book can just have a keeper

Comment: @Paulw11, omg thank you so much, I thought `@Relationship` was only for deleting policy

Comment: If this has been resolved then please remove the question or post an answer

Comment: Still don't know why the crash happens. Paul only explained duplicates part

Comment: Have you found the reason of the crash?

Comment: @Paulw11's answer works. I posted as a solution just in case. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution from @Paulw11 (unfortunately it is just posted as a comment):

> Properties in your model that are a relationship to another entity need the @Relationship decorator. You don't really need the Ownership class. A book can just have a keeper

So, just use @Relationship, and you can indeed just store the owner in the book

Answer (score 0):

add the model container like this after the WindowGroup of the App.swift file
.modelContainer(for: [Ownership.self, User.self, Book.self])
//SwiftData will infer the dependencies of the items in the above array, so it is not necessary to add them all, but you can if you want

Pass the model context that is assumed by SwiftData into the file you need it in:
@Environment(.modelContext) var modelContext
Then add to it like this:
modelContext.insert(objectNameHere)

book exists twice because you init it in the class and call it again in ownership.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to initialize `keeper` and `user` variable properties outside of `Ownership.init()`

I mean this:

```
@Model
final class Ownership {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var keeper: User?
    var book: Book?

    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
    }
    func makeConstraint(keeper: User, book: Book) {
        self.keeper = keeper
        self.book = book
    }
}
```